# Error creating room using Smack: "Feature not implemented"

Tags: xmpp, smack, multiuserchat

I'm following the documentation and trying to create a room:

```
  //Create a MultiUserChat using a Connection for a room
  MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(conn1, "myroom@mycompany.com");

  // Create the room
  muc.create("testroom");

  // Send an empty room configuration form which indicates that we want
  // an instant room
  muc.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT));
```

When I go into PSI, click service discovery, click multiuserchat, right click browse, click myroom. It pops an error message, that says "There was an error getting agents for myroom@mycompany.com, Reason: Feature not implemented. The feature requested is not implemented by the recipient server and cannot be processed".

Any suggestions, anyone?

Now I can create a new room using PSI. I also tried muc.join instead of muc.create. Same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your exact setup, I would guess that your room name (`myroom@mycompany.com`) is incorrect. You get a `Feature not implemented` because the XMPP entity `mycompany.com` does likely not act as MUC service. Those are implemented as separate XMPP component, usually named `conference` or `muc`, e.g. `conference.mycompany.com`.